# Python - Check if two words are in a string

Tags: python

I would like to check whether 2 words "car" and "motorbike" are in each element of an array in Python. I know how to check for one word with `in` but have no idea how to do with 2 words. Really appreciate any help

Comment: Use the logical AND operator: `if cond1 and cond2:`

Comment: Just use the `and` operator

Answer (score 8):

Two word solution:

```
for string in array:
    if 'car' in string and 'motorbike' in string.split():
        print("Car and motorbike are in string")
```

n-word solution to check if **all** words in `test_words` are in `string`:

```
test_words = ['car', 'motorbike']
contains_all = True

for string in array:
    for test_word in test_words:
        if test_word not in string.split()::
            contains_all = False
            break
    if not contains_all:
        break

if contains_all:
    print("All words in each string")
else:
    print("Not all words in each string")
```

Comment: `all(map(lambda w: w in text, ('car', 'motorbike')))` is much cleaner...

Comment: Well, in a way you are right. However, it depends on what you mean by clean. When you go through each line of my code, it is very obvious what is happening, whereas in your line, I may understand what is happening and so do you, but a beginner may not understand it. My answer was written in a way a beginner should be able to understand what is happening and not as a oneliner to be copy-pasted. However, in the way that your solution takes up less space for the same thing and may even be faster, you are right!

Comment: `if 'car' in string and 'motorbike' in string.split():` why not splitting in both cases?

Answer (score 1):

Use an auxiliar boolean.

```
car=False
 motorbike=False
 for elem in array:

        if "car" in elem:
            car=True
        if "motorbike" in elem:
            motorbike=True
        if car and motorbike:
            break
```

EDIT: I just read "in each element". Just use AND.

Comment: use `print` to indicate there is match or not

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple solution is this:

```py
all(map(lambda w: w in text, ('car', 'motorbike')))
```

But there might be a problem with this, depending on how picky you need the comparison to be:

```py
>>> text = 'Can we buy motorbikes in carshops?'
>>> all(map(lambda w: w in text, ('car', 'motorbike')))
True
```

The words 'car' and 'motorbike' are NOT in the `text`, and this still says `True`. You might need a full match in words. I would do this:

```py
>>> words = ('car', 'motorbike')
>>> text = 'Can we buy motorbikes in carshops?'
>>> set(words).issubset(text.split())
False
>>> text = 'a car and a motorbike'
>>> set(words).issubset(text.split())
True
```

And now it works!

Comment: No need for `set` conversion in the parameter to `issubset`, the method takes an iterable:`set(words).issubset(text.split())`

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `all` function:

```
wanted_values = ("car", "motorbike")
all(vehicle in text for text in wanted_values)
```

So if we have a list of strings:

```
l = ['some car and motorbike',
     'a motorbike by a car',
     'the car was followed by a motorbike']

lines_with_vehicles = [text for text in l
                       if all(vehicle in text for text in wanted_values)]
```

With regex you could do:

```
# no particular order
car_and_motorbike_pattern = re.compile(r'(car.*motorbike|motorbike.*car)')
all(car_and_motorbike_pattern.search(text) for text in list_of_expressions)

# This works too
car_or_motorbike_pattern = re.compile(r'(car|motorbike)')
get_vehicles = car_or_motorbike_pattern.findall
all(len(set(get_vehicles(text))) == 2 for text in list_of_expressions)
```

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-check-if-given-words-appear-together-in-a-list-of-sentence/) worked for me:
It offers 3 solutions. Two methods use list comprehensions and the third one uses map + lambda functions.

---

I think there is not an easy and pythonic way to do that.  You need to use an ugly logic like the next:

```
image_file_name = 'man_in_car.jpg'
if 'car' in image_file_name and 'man' in image_file_name:
    print('"car" and "man" were found in the image_file_name')
```

That would work for two words, but if you need to check many words, then better use the code in the link above

---

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
if 'car' and 'man' in image_file_name:
    print('"car" and "man" were found in the image_file_name')
```

Or:

```
if any(['car','man'] in image_file_name):
    print('"car" and "man" were found in the image_file_name')
```

But these 2 last pieces of code don't work in python (yet).

Comment: I just tested and found that this works: if value1 in string and value2 in string. Just need two in statements

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to check for two or more keywords in a sentence with 'and' or 'or' operators.

```
def check_words(operator = 'and', words = ['car', 'bike'],
                sentence = 'I own a car but not a bike'):

    if operator == 'and':
        word_present = True
        for w in words:
            if w in sentence:
                word_present = True
            else:
                word_present = False
        return word_present

    elif operator == 'or':
        for w in words:
            if w in sentence:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        

check_words(operator = 'and', words = ['car', 'bike'],
            sentence = 'I own a car but not a bike')
```