# Search for words in Pandas Series using Python

Tags: python, pandas, pattern-matching

I am trying to search for words in string `account lock` in text encoded as Pandas Series. 
Currently, I am using `contains` function.

If text is `account lock email` I am getting correct results.

```
>>> pd.Series('account lock email').str.contains('account lock', case=False)
0    True
dtype: bool
```

But if text is `lock email account` I am getting result `False`.

```
>>> pd.Series('lock email account').str.contains('account lock', case=False)
0    False
dtype: bool
```

Also if text is `account email lock` I am getting result `False`.

```
>>> pd.Series('account email lock').str.contains('account lock', case=False)
0    False
dtype: bool
```

Is there any way that `contains` function can be used to check if all words in a specified string are present in Pandas Series?

Or is there any alternative?

Got required results using below code using all function

```
>>> all(x in ('lock email account').split() for x in ('account lock').split())
True
>>> all(x in ('account email lock').split() for x in ('account lock').split())
True
>>> all(x in ('account email').split() for x in ('account lock').split())
False
```

Comment: Try to use search for every word  individually

Comment: You have several pandas solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011734).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if two words are in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088559/python-check-if-two-words-are-in-a-string)

They suggest using the `all` function.

Comment: You can use regex.
Here's how you can
`pd.Series('lock email account').str.contains('account|lock', case=False)`

Comment: @FChm, Thanks for your suggestion , I able to get require results using all function, I have edit my question with all command

Comment: @MayurBhangale, Thanks for your suggestion, your suggestion also worked but I was also looking for code which will be looking for getting True results when both  words will be available in text , If i use | as below getting True as result (>>> pd.Series('lock account').str.contains('account|lock', case=False) 
0    True
dtype: bool)